# How to extend docker compose files with smillar service names?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my scenario, I aim to deploy Docker containers via Docker Compose across various environments, each with specific user requirements. Consequently, we've opted to employ multiple Docker Compose files. To enhance management, we seek to create a centralized compose file and extend it to other Docker Compose files. Given that we're using the same Docker Compose service names in both files, is it feasible to accomplish this?

Does anyone have examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to achieve this,

This is our main docker-compose file,

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  backend:
    image: backend:latest
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file:
    - ./env_files/common.env
    - ./env_files/backend.env
  frontend:
    image: frontend:latest
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    env_file:
    - ./env_files/common.env
    - ./env_files/frontend.env

  apigateway:
    image: apigateway:latest
    container_name: apigateway
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8888:8888"
    env_file:
      - ./env_files/common.env
      - ./env_files/apigateway.env
```

Then we created a separate file by extending the main docker-compose,

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  backend:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.yaml
      service: backend
  frontend:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.yaml
      service: frontend
  apigateway:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.yaml
      service: apigateway
    environment:
      - DOCKER_BACKEND_URL=example.com
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```